# Expandable/Dynamic/Variable div heights

Tags: html, css

I have three divs

```
#header
#content
#footer
```

I want them to consume 100% (height) of the window, but I want them to scale accordingly.

I've tried assigning percentage heights to each div but I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a cross-browser tutorial to achieve what you need.

http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=144